return value unclicking html checkbox
I try to make a checkbox that should return true if I select it and false if I deselect it.
<input type="checkbox" id="10101" name="10101" 
onchange="update_C('10101', 40)" value="true">

and then I accsess the value inside update_C with
document.getElementById('10101').value

However, this always returns true, every time the checkbox gets selected or deselected.
I found some suggestions how to implement this, but they are quite old and I didn't manage to make them work. Are there any "new" solutions how this problem can be solved?
One work around would be using radio buttons with true/false values, but I would prefer checkboxes.

The value of a checkbox does not change, just because you check or uncheck the element.

"and then I accsess the value inside update_C with [...]" - why? If you need to know whether the user checked the field or not - then query its checked property?

You can use the checked property to check if the checkbox is selected


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="vi">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Checkbox Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="10101" name="10101" onchange="update_C('10101', 40)">

    <script>
        function update_C(id, value) {
            let isChecked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
            console.log(isChecked);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>




I strongly advice external event handling and possibly delegation - especially if there are more than one checkbox

Thank you. I am simply illustrating how to utilize the 'checked' property. So I wrote the javascript in the 'html' file.

You have set the value="true" and then ask for it. Therefore you get true no matter whether the checkbox is checked or not. You need to ask for propery checked.
document.getElementById('10101').checked;


PS: JQuery should not be necessary in your case

Using jQuery just for this use case would be bad advice even. You will load a complete js library just to check a checkbox.

Well I kind of supposed the library isnt known to the poster so just in case he might like it and consider it helpful for his project, the tag is there. Also edited the suggestion

If jQuery isn't known to the poster or it isn't asked, don't advise it . Using jQuery in 2024 is considered bad practice. The opposite is actually advised now. Most developers want to kill jQuery and there are good reasons for that.
